# How to hide base price in category view (MAGENTO)?

Tags: magento, categories, configurable

I've setup a simple product with custom options but I would like to hide the base price from the category page (list or grid mode).
How can I do this ?

I highlighted the "price" I would like to remove :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBMzs.png

**Here you have my price.phtml code : http://pastebin.com/JGjSQDB7**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would hide it using CSS, that will likely be the easiest way to hide the price. I'm not sure what your selectors are called. If you include a link to the site I'm sure you can be helped!

Comment: In fact, I could hide completely both prices but not only the first one (commenting out a php line). You can see the page at http://extremedata.ca/magento/index.php/ordinateurs-de-bureau.html

Comment: With a little bit of CSS such as `.category-products .regular-price .price { display: none; }` it will hide the price just like you want. Since the `category-products` selector is **only** called on those page sit should work. See the [image](http://img145.imageshack.us/img145/9241/siteqm.png)

Comment: Thank you ! CSS is very usefull in that case :)

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('.price-box').each(function () {
        if (jQuery(this).find(jQuery('.minimal-price-link')).length > 0) {
            jQuery(this).find('.regular-price').hide();
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have jQuery installed, you can do the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('.price-box').each(function () {
        if (jQuery(this).find(jQuery('.minimal-price-link')).length > 0) {
            jQuery(this).find('.regular-price').hide();
        }
    })
})
```

This loops through `.price-box` individually and will conditionally hide `.regular-price` depending on the availability of `.minimal-price-link` in that given box.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm not familiar with jQuery. I search a little bit about that language but can't find any information about integration in a website. Where do I put your code ? I'll copy-paste my page code (mainly PHP) here if it can help you solve this "problem". Thanks again!

Comment: wrap it in <script type="text/javascript"> and place it in your catalog/product/list.phtml and also catalog/product/view.phtml if required.

Comment: Thanks  however as i'm not familiar with jQuery I couldn't get it to work so I used CSS.

Comment: jQuery was already installed, you just needed to paste in the code in the right file. Anyway if CSS gives you trouble, you can try my method - it's tested.

Comment: Also careful with the CSS method as it can hide prices from view even if when you want it to show.